# Index not being used in range query

Tags: mysql

Hello I have this query

```
SELECT * FROM customers WHERE height > 180 AND height < 200
```

and here's the result of `explain` applied to it:

```
mysql> explain SELECT * FROM customers WHERE height > 180 AND height < 200;
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows  | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | customers | ALL  | height        | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 10423 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-------+-------------+
```

Note that there is a index for the field `height` which is not being picked up, somehow...

The `height` field is a integer. I dunno. I was expecting it to be used and also the `type` to be `range`

Anyone?

Comment: Can you include the definition of the height Index?

Comment: show us the actual table `customers` structure.

Comment: How many of the records on the table fall into that range of heights?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the specified range. Too loose apparently. Mysql prefer a full scan rather than using the index in this special case. If I restrict the range, or increment the number of records the `height` index is used and the search access strategy turns into `range` as per manual.

Comment: The size of the subset before MySQL chooses to do a full table scan seems to vary a bit. Out of interest roughly what percentage of your records fall into that range? Pity someone deleted the other answers.